# R Change ggplot geom_quasirandom colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, aes, geom, beeswarm

R newbie on deck,
Hi everybody !

I wrote a code to visualize a geom_quasirandom (library `GGbeeswarm` ) for my dataset.
What works is to visualize it, but with 3 random colors for the 3 species in the dataset.
However, i do want to customize the colors of those 3 to my own specific.
But its not working and i dont know how to adjust my code.

My dataset is the "palmer penguins".
Code is:

```
ggplot(penguins, aes(sex, body_mass_g, color = species)) +
  geom_quasirandom() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(Chinstrap = "#C35CCA", Gentoo = "#0F7075", Adelie = "#FF8305")) +
  labs(x = "Sex", y = "Bodymass", title = "Penguins bodymass by gender")
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Try with `scale_color_manual`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39129209/10276092